# Vertical Swiper on ul lost right side border-radius?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to use idangerous swiper on ul. But something wrong happened.

- Right side border-radius lost.
- I tried to set swiper-container fixed height but it didn't have any effect.

Can someone give me a hint?

[JSFiddle][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/lqp2792/7z2o58z4/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://jsfiddle.net/lqp2792/7z2o58z4/

Add:

```
.swiper-container {
  overflow:visible;
 }
```

In your css file.